# add 'time' to 'follow up flag' in outlook 2003?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2003, gtd, reminder, flag

It would appear that the dialog for setting 'follow up flags' in Outlook 2003 is limited to date only.

Does anyone know of a workaround to add a time to this?

Comment: Interested in GTD? Join [Personal Productivity and Organization](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4296/personal-productivity-and-organization-gtd-covey-etc), we are looking for users & experts... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adolf, here is what you should do to have it done correctly. I tested it with my Office 2003 machine and it seems to work fine. I get the Due date and time I can chose among the drop down list.

1. Open the message or contact you want to change the due date for.
2. Click Follow Up .
3. Enter a date and time in the Due by boxes.

   **Note**:    Items past their due date appear as the color set in the Automatic Format 
   dialog box. By default, flagged items past their due date are red.

So if this is not what you get, please try a repair on a fresh reinstall. Let me know...

Comment: I'd never thought to click on that right-hand drop down...ooops.